# Resubmit app to google play after rejection

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Basically i got rejected for things in the description in which they did specify (very cool), and i resubmitted.
That was 12 hours ago, and just to point out, it still says rejected but there's that "your app is under review" thingy under the "Rejected", kinda worried it isn't being reviewed but nonetheless, if anyone has this kind of experience, do they take this long just to resubmit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same issue, my app was rejected so I made updates. After clicking "Resubmit App", I get an alert saying "App Saved". But I still have the warning flags within the dashboard saying "App rejected", I don't know if this is from the previous rejection or not. It's confusing.

Comment: it will keep saying rejected although it actually is awaiting reverification so don't worry.

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have sent a support ticket saying they take over 2 days

Edit: App is published and i've never been happier lmao <3